# ARC - ObjC Objects with CF instance variables

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

I think I'm being a bone head here...

The static analyzer complains in the `-(void)doSomethingInteresting` method:

> Potential leak of an object stored into myAddressBook

Well, sure, that makes sense; I'm calling a `create` function without a matching `release`. But, I don't think I want to release `myAddressBook` at the end of `-doSomethingInteresting` because I want it to stick around for the life of the `AwesomeObject` instance.

*AwesomeObject.h*

```
@interface AwesomeObject : NSObject

@property (assign, nonatomic) ABAddressBookRef addressBook;

@end
```

*AwesomeObject.m*

```
@implementation AwesomeObject

- (void)doSomethingInteresting
{
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef myAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

    [self setAddressBook:myAddressBook];
}

@end
```

EDIT: Screen shot attached

[image: Static Analyzer Arrows]

Comment: the property should retain, then you should release... that way the object is the owner rather than the local scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The analyzer doesn't understand you wish to assign a retained address book in your property, and thus not release it at the end of `doSomethingInteresting`.

Change your property to:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id addressBook;
```

and set it like so:

```
[self setAddressBook:CFBridgingRelease(addressBook)];
```

Now, when you want to use the `addressBook` property,  use the `(__bridge ABAddressBookRef)` cast.

Also, you need to release a potential `CFErrorRef` object, which may have been created during `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions`:

```
if(error)
{
    CFRelease(error);
    error = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it like this:

```
 [self setAddressBook:CFBridgingRelease(myAddressBook)];
```

Comment: And see my book to learn why: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management_of_cftyperefs

Comment: The property is defined as `assign`.

Comment: It shouldn't be. :) It should be `strong` as usual (it should be an `id`), and we just hand it over to ARC to manage until the end of time.

Comment: For a real-life example, see https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch18p713addressBook/ch31p973addressBook/ViewController.m

Comment: I went down this rabbit hole. It gives the "Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'id' to C pointer type 'ABAddressBookRef' requires a bridge cast"

Comment: That's when you want to reference it later. So perform the cast! Cast the id to `(__bridge ABAddressBookRef)`. Please actually _look_ at the example I pointed you to, it shows the whole thing.

Comment: @matt Yes, I know what it should be, but you should have pointed it in your answer, instead of pointing to your book.

Comment: @LeoNatan I don't agree. I answered the question he _asked_ - I told him how to quiet the worries of the static analyzer about this line of code. The other stuff (the bridge cast) was in response to his comments. And I'm not going to repeat here a long tutorial explanation that it has taken me years to perfect; the explanation in the book is free to read, and the sample code I pointed to is free to look at: all he has to do is click. Moreover, the URLs could change, but the answer will not.

Comment: @matt Took me 2 minutes to write the answer, and a few more to "perfect" it. There comes a time where advertising your stuff is just blatantly bad.

Comment: @LeoNatan It's not advertising! It's free tutorial material like any other. I've deliberately put this stuff on the Web to make it public and available for free. That's not bad, it's good.

Comment: @matt Better is to provide all information required for a correct **and full** answer, and then link to a more in-depth look at a tutorial, yours or anyone else's.

Comment: @LeoNatan and that is what I thought I did. Hey, the marketplace decided - you got several upvotes and the checkmark, why be a bad winner? That's why Stack Overflow is great!